# How to recover an iPad from power-off during an upgrade?

Tags: ipad, software-update

I upgraded my iPad 2 from iOS 6 to iOS 8.

However, I cancelled the upgrade by turning the iPad off because I thought that my files weren't backed up to a PC. I used OtA upgrade.

When I turn the iPad back on, there's an image of USB connector and iTunes icon signifying to connect it to iTunes.

Would all my files (photos, paid apps, memorable videos, etc.) still restore to my iPad if I restore from iTunes?

Comment: At this step of the upgrade process, it's too late to think about missing backups and there is no way except plugging your iPad into the USB connector to proceed.

Comment: I did not connected my ipad yet to itunes. I didn't checked yet my files.

Comment: In the state your iPad is in ("connect to iTunes" on display) there isn't really an alternative to just proceeding and hoping for the best.

Answer (score 1):

No - you would need to try to back up over USB to PhoneView or a similar tool.

Once you're sure you can't get any data back, then connecting to iTunes can easily wipe whatever's left and then return a proper working OS onto the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

When you see the itunes logo with your charging cable on your iPad, it means that your device is in DFU (Device Firmware Update) mode.the only thing you could do now is to restore the iPad via iTunes. It is **not** possible to make a backup anymore.